# making small changes to modules in the play framework

Tags: playframework

I'm using the securesocial module in google app engine.  Because html emails do not work (only text emails), I need to put in a fix.  The fix is to replace sendActivationEmail.html with a new file sendActivationEmail.txt.  If the html file exists at all, the play mailer will pick it up first.  What is the best way to do this?

I have a method but it involves using local copies of all my modules.  I use:

```
rm modules/* # remove module link files
play deps --forceCopy # copy external modules into ./modules/...
```

Then I customize the local version in my app's home directory.  One side note, I put the rm command in a configuration script and check-in only sendActivationEmail.txt.

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you need a custom version of a module, your best bet is to copy it and attach it to the source of your application (while still keeping it as a module), so you can tinker with it as much as you want.

That will make it easier to add further changes if required.

Comment: I got the copy part: "play deps --forceCopy" .. I'm not sure what you mean by attach it to the source.

Comment: I mean to keep it on the same repository (svn/git/etc) as part of the codebase, in a specific folder (modules or something similar), so you can track your own changes